# What best practices for VAE do you know?

Tags: keras, pytorch, variational-autoencoder, diffusion-models

The data is `binary voxel` data of shape `(60, 36, 60)`. I want to compress such data into `lower latent space` to be able to use the `denoising diffusion model`. What best practices (model architecture, depth, etc.) do you suggest to get the most out of the `VAE`?

Here is my implementation of VAE:

```
# encoder
voxel_size = (60, 36, 60, 1)
encoder_inputs = tf.keras.Input(shape=voxel_size)
x = tf.keras.layers.Conv3D(64, 3, padding='same')(encoder_inputs)
x = VAEResidualBlock(64, name='residual_0')(x)
x = VAEResidualBlock(64, name='residual_1')(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.Conv3D(64, 3, strides=2, padding='same')(x)
x = VAEResidualBlock(128, name='residual_2')(x)
x = VAEResidualBlock(128, name='residual_3')(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.Conv3D(128, 3, strides=2, padding='same')(x)
x = VAEResidualBlock(256, name='residual_4')(x)
x = VAEResidualBlock(256, name='residual_5')(x)
x = VAEResidualBlock(256, name='residual_8')(x)
x = VAEAttentionBlock(256, name='attention_0')(x)
x = VAEResidualBlock(256, name='residual_9')(x)
x = GroupNormalization(256, name='group_normalization_0')(x)
x = tf.keras.activations.swish(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.Conv3D(8, 3, padding='same')(x)
z_mean = tf.keras.layers.Conv3D(4, 1, padding='valid', name='z_mean')(x)
z_log_var = tf.keras.layers.Conv3D(4, 1, padding='valid', name='z_log_var')(x)
encoder = tf.keras.Model(encoder_inputs, [z_mean, z_log_var], name='encoder')
encoder.summary()

# decoder
latent_inputs = tf.keras.Input(shape=(15, 9, 15, 4))
x = tf.keras.layers.Conv3D(4, 1, padding='valid')(latent_inputs)
x = tf.keras.layers.Conv3D(256, 3, padding='same')(x)
x = VAEResidualBlock(256)(x)
x = VAEAttentionBlock(256)(x)
x = VAEResidualBlock(256)(x)
x = VAEResidualBlock(256)(x)
x = VAEResidualBlock(256)(x)
x = VAEResidualBlock(256)(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.UpSampling3D(2)(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.Conv3D(256, 3, padding='same')(x)
x = VAEResidualBlock(128)(x)
x = VAEResidualBlock(128)(x)
x = VAEResidualBlock(128)(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.UpSampling3D(2)(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.Conv3D(128, 3, padding='same')(x)
x = VAEResidualBlock(64)(x)
x = VAEResidualBlock(64)(x)
x = VAEResidualBlock(64)(x)
x = GroupNormalization(64)(x)
x = tf.keras.activations.swish(x)
decoder_outputs = tf.keras.layers.Conv3D(1, 3, activation='sigmoid', padding='same')(x)
decoder = tf.keras.Model(latent_inputs, decoder_outputs, name='decoder')
decoder.summary()

# sampler
class Sampler(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def call(self, z_mean, z_log_var):
        batch_size = tf.shape(z_mean)[0]
        z_size = tf.shape(z_mean)[1]
        epsilon = tf.random.normal(shape=tf.shape(z_mean))
        # epsilon = tf.random.normal(shape=(batch_size, z_size))
        # print(z_mean.shape, epsilon.shape)
        return z_mean + tf.exp(0.5*z_log_var) * epsilon

# VAE
class VAE(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self, encoder, decoder, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.encoder = encoder
        self.decoder = decoder
        self.sampler = Sampler()
        self.total_loss_tracker = tf.keras.metrics.Mean(name='total_loss')
        self.reconstruction_loss_tracker = tf.keras.metrics.Mean(name='reconstruction_loss')
        self.kl_loss_tracker = tf.keras.metrics.Mean(name='kl_loss')

    @property
    def metrics(self):
        return [self.total_loss_tracker,
                self.reconstruction_loss_tracker,
                self.kl_loss_tracker]

    def train_step(self, data):
        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
            z_mean, z_log_var = self.encoder(data)
            z = self.sampler(z_mean, z_log_var)
            reconstruction = decoder(z)
            reconstruction_loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.reduce_sum(tf.keras.losses.binary_crossentropy(data, reconstruction),
                                                                               axis=(1, 2, 3)))
            kl_loss = -0.5 * (1+z_log_var-tf.square(z_mean)-tf.exp(z_log_var))
            total_loss = reconstruction_loss + tf.reduce_mean(kl_loss)
        grads = tape.gradient(total_loss, self.trainable_weights)
        self.optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, self.trainable_weights))
        self.total_loss_tracker.update_state(total_loss)
        self.reconstruction_loss_tracker.update_state(reconstruction_loss)
        self.kl_loss_tracker.update_state(kl_loss)
        return {'total_loss': self.total_loss_tracker.result(),
                'reconstruction_loss': self.reconstruction_loss_tracker.result(),
                'kl_loss': self.kl_loss_tracker.result()}

vae = VAE(encoder, decoder)
vae.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(), run_eagerly=True)
vae.fit(voxel_arrays, epochs=150, batch_size=4,
        callbacks=[tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='total_loss', 
                                                            patience=5),
                   tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint('/home/r.abdrakhmanov/diffvox/models/vae.keras',
                                                              monitor='total_loss',
                                                              mode='min',
                                                              save_best_only=True,
                                                              save_weights_only=True)])
```

But the best possible `total_loss` so far:

```
Epoch 26/150
362/362 [==============================] - 552s 2s/step - total_loss: 20168.3750 - reconstruction_loss: 20089.0879 - kl_loss: 79.2998
Epoch 27/150
362/362 [==============================] - 555s 2s/step - total_loss: 19650.8145 - reconstruction_loss: 19571.0508 - kl_loss: 79.7697
Epoch 28/150
362/362 [==============================] - 540s 1s/step - total_loss: 19981.1680 - reconstruction_loss: 19898.7871 - kl_loss: 82.3754
Epoch 29/150
362/362 [==============================] - 550s 2s/step - total_loss: 19577.8027 - reconstruction_loss: 19502.1582 - kl_loss: 75.6499
Epoch 30/150
362/362 [==============================] - 535s 1s/step - total_loss: 20013.8477 - reconstruction_loss: 19934.2266 - kl_loss: 79.6151
Epoch 31/150
362/362 [==============================] - 528s 1s/step - total_loss: 19767.3184 - reconstruction_loss: 19687.5156 - kl_loss: 79.7937
Epoch 32/150
362/362 [==============================] - 516s 1s/step - total_loss: nan - reconstruction_loss: nan - kl_loss: nan
Epoch 33/150
362/362 [==============================] - 517s 1s/step - total_loss: nan - reconstruction_loss: nan - kl_loss: nan
Epoch 34/150
362/362 [==============================] - 527s 1s/step - total_loss: nan - reconstruction_loss: nan - kl_loss: nan
```